# Is it estimated that nearly half of USA jobs be low wage service jobs by 2040?

Tags: economics

According to yesmagazine.org's post [A Wealthy Capitalist on Why Money Doesn't Trickle Down](http://www.yesmagazine.org/issues/the-end-of-poverty/wealthy-capitalist-nick-hanauer-on-why-money-doesn-t-trickle-down),

> By 2040, it is estimated that 48 percent of all American jobs will be low-wage service jobs.

The claim also occurred again on thestanger.com's [post](http://www.thestranger.com/seattle/how-a-15-minimum-wage-would-make-everyone-richer/Content?oid=19138455):

> By 2040, it is estimated that 48 percent of all American jobs will be low-wage service jobs.

This claim has been repeated on many sites and I'm skeptical about it. While we certainly can't know that future, we can predict it. I would like to know if there is a scientific study or a statistical methodology explaining the reason behind this claim, and what backing does it have if it exists?

Comment: I won't be surprised if this was based on [this study](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2609391/Rise-robots-Humans-compete-droids-jobs-2040-study-claims.html) projecting we're going to be competing for jobs with robots by 2040, but I can't find a direct correlation.

Comment: Reopened after extensive editing. Thanks to all for improving.

Comment: Here's a possible source (word-for-word) for the claim, from March 2014: <http://www.thestranger.com/seattle/how-a-15-minimum-wage-would-make-everyone-richer/Content?oid=19138455>. No source given there, either. Call me dubious.